# Three.js mouse picking object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, .obj

So i found a lot of tutorials on how to use mouse picking on default objects available in Threejs itself, but is it possible to use mouse picking on imported models like a .obj file and displaying a sphere at the exact position where the user clicks the model?
If so, can someone give me a tutorial or at least an example with source code so i can use it.
I prefer a tutorial, because thats a better way to learn it. ;)

EDIT: So i got mouse picking working for the model! But now i want to show a little dot at the location where the user clicks the model. I tried to do it the way this demo works: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes but can't get it to work, someone who knows why? See code below

```
// once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var stats = initStats();
var particleMaterial;

// create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
particleMaterial = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
    color: 0x000000,
    program: function ( context ) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
        context.fill();
    }
});
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


// create a render and set the size
var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEFEFEF, 1.0));
webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
webGLRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

// position and point the camera to the center of the scene
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 40;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));


var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 3.0;
trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 3.0;
trackballControls.panSpeed = 0.4;
trackballControls.staticMoving = false;

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);
hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF, 0.9 ); 
scene.add(hemiLight);
// add spotlight for the shadows
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set(300, 300, 300);
spotLight.intensity = 1;
scene.add(spotLight);

// add the output of the renderer to the html element
$("#WebGL-output").append(webGLRenderer.domElement);

// call the render function
var step = 0;


// setup the control gui
//var controls = new function () {
    // we need the first child, since it's a multimaterial


//}

//var gui = new dat.GUI();
var mesh;
var objects = [];

var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    var object = event.content;
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            //The child is the bit needed for the raycaster.intersectObject() method
        }
    } );
    object.scale.set(4, 4, 4);
    object.position.set(0, -10, 0);
    object.name = "test";
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);
});

loader.load('models/dancer07.obj', 'models/dancer07.mtl', {side: THREE.DoubleSide});

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 400, 50, 50), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x808080, wireframe: true }));
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
plane.name = 'Ground';
plane.position.set(0, -10, 0);
scene.add(plane);
objects.push(plane);

render();

function render() {
    stats.update();
    var delta = clock.getDelta();

    if (mesh) {
        //   mesh.rotation.y+=0.006;
    }


    trackballControls.update(delta);

    //webGLRenderer.clear();
    // render using requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera)
}

function initStats() {

    var stats = new Stats();
    stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

    // Align top-left
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

    $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

    return stats;
}
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false ); 

function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1;
    var mouseY = -(event.clientY /window.innerHeight)*2+1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouseX, mouseY, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        alert("intersect!");
        var particle = new THREE.Sprite( particleMaterial );
        particle.position.copy( intersects[0].point );
        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 300;
        scene.add(particle);    
    }

}

$('#reset').click(function() {
    trackballControls.reset();
});

$('#female').click(function() {
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("test"));
    loader.load('models/dancer07.obj', 'models/dancer07.mtl', {side: THREE.DoubleSide});
});

$('#male').click(function() {
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("test"));
    loader.load('models/doorman.obj', 'models/doorman.mtl', {side: THREE.DoubleSide});
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but the answer was not 100% complete, since i asked before if someone knew if and how to display a sphere. And because it didn't work I decided to update my question by adding the code and the solution i tried as a description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if its an imported model or a default object. The mouse picking code in the Three.JS examples works with any sort of mesh.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_buffergeometry

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
```

Use the meshes created by the loader in the `raycaster.intersectObject` function. In your case you could get all of the meshes that compose an object with the below loading code.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'example.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            //The child is the bit needed for the raycaster.intersectObject() method
        }
    } );
    object.position.y = - 80;
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks it did work! I updated my question because i thought that it then was easy to display a sphere / dot. But it wasn't. please help.