# Grab WebGL object in Browser (Window) Coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, three.js, webgl

I have a WebGL project setup that I would like to put an SVG mapping on top of.

The reason for WebGL is to make a book with flipping pages. (I need to use WebGL for this)
The reason for SVG is to map boxes over the words in the WebGL texture.

I have the WebGL book, and I have the SVG setup. I just need to know the best way to integrate the two of them together.

My first thought (because I'm not really that well versed in WebGL just yet), is to just place the SVG absolute positioned over the WebGL canvas and that should work fine.

But the problem is that I cannot retrieve the coordinates of the WebGL object. I have been looking for any function or property that this can be found/calculated and am getting nowhere.

So how would I find the browser window coordinates of the top-left corner of a page (texture, material) element in WebGL.

Is this even possible?

If you have any other suggestions on how to accomplish this, I'm willing to do anything, but I must remind you that I am stuck to WebGL for this for the book part. I am willing to give up on the SVG if there is a better suited option available.

**UPDATE:**
I know that you can change x, y and z of the object (material, texture), or even move the camera in or out on the zindex which can affect what you are seeing. But what I'm looking for is if there a way to get the Browser Screen pixel coordinates relating to the browser window regardless of where the object, camera, etc is positioned?

For example, if I have a cube setup on the WebGL canvas that fills the entire browser window (width:100% and height:100%). How can I tell where that cube is relating to the browser window (not from within the canvas) (value in pixels)?
I am essentially looking for the equivalent of the jQuery function offset() but finding the object within the WebGL canvas (top left coordinates) but relating to the window. And say I zoom in using the camera, technically the object has not moved, but the object became smaller on the screen. How could I then know the coordinates relating to the window (because the coordinates in WebGL will remain the same)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three.js mouse picking object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667394/three-js-mouse-picking-object)

Comment: Thanks for your response but my question has nothing to do with mouse picking. I'm assuming you're saying I should use mouse picking over my current plan, but the main question I need answered is can I get the browser window coordinates of an object in my WebGL canvas?

Comment: You just need to do on the CPU what you're already doing on the GPU, projecting points onto the screen. Just take your point and shove it through the transform chain Model->View->Projection. Ray picking is just reversing this process, so it has a lot todo with what you're asking for ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm just really new to this and have no clue what you mean. I am just using some example code I found online to get started with this, but I have a project of this book set up, I just need this one top-left coordinate of this Material/Texture that I have loaded from an image. I'm confused as to where the mouse comes into it. I need the absolute window coordinate of this texture right after it loads. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but I really am anxious for an answer to this. I've been trying to research this all day and cannot figure out in what direction you are pointing me in. If you could please read my previous comment and give me some direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Instead of my badly written answer try [looking at this this](http://webglfactory.blogspot.de/2011/05/how-to-convert-world-to-screen.html)

Comment: @bOkeifus Don't start out something with projects. In a project you want to get something done no matter how. What you want is to learn as much as possible, no matter how little you seem to get done :)